# How to I print line numbers in my output for my prime number range program?

Tags: java

```
package computing.primes;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputingPrimes {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Prime Range Calculator!");
        int sc1, sc2, sc3, flag = 0, i, j;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the lower limit : ");
        sc1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the upper limit : ");
        sc2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The prime numbers between the limits are : ");
        for(i = sc1; i <= sc2; i++)
        {
            for(j = 2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 1)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output is reading as

Welcome to the Prime Range Calculator!

Enter the lower limit : 1

Enter the upper limit : 100

The prime numbers between the limits are :

3

5

7

11

13

17

19

23

29

31

37

41

43

47

53

59

61

67

71

73

79

83

89

97

when I want it to number each line of the primes in sequence.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve or what is wrong with the code. It would help if you would show an example of the **desired output**. If I got you correct, you want the numbers in one line instead of each in a single line. The answer is simple, do not use `println` (print line), instead use `print`. Always read the **documentation** of methods you are using, to make sure you understand what they are doing: [PrintStream#println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int))

Comment: sorry I'm new here so the formatting threw me off. I meant how to number each line in the output in sequence. I got my answer to that but now I'm trying to figure out why the program isn't calculating 2 as a prime number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `int counter = 0;` **before** the `for` loop. Then change

```
System.out.println(i);
```

to

```
System.out.printf("%d %d%n", ++counter, i);
```

Also, `2` is prime.

Comment: It may help if you add a version that does use the ordinary `println` method, but achieves the same. `System.out.println(++counter + " " + i);`

Comment: Thank you! How would I alter it to calculate 2 as a prime number? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Tyler Put `flag = 1;` before the inner `for` loop. Remove the `else` (since it's now redundant).